# Как растянуть свой Bottom Sheet наполовину

Tags: android, material-design

у меня есть макет

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed" />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


    <include layout="@layout/content_main_weather_map" />

    <include layout="@layout/bottom_sheet" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Bottom Sheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:clipToPadding="true"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="80dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/weather_recycler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            tools:listitem="@layout/item_weather" />

    </LinearLayout>


</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Мне необходимо чтоб при загрузке отображалась только небольшая его часть (это я реализовал), после свайпа вверх открывался на половину и далее после повторного свайпа он раскрывался на весь экран, как это сделано в Google Maps. Но я понятия не имею как мне это сделать, убил добрых часов 5, буду рад любой помощи.

Comment: https://github.com/fish-4-fun/like-google-maps

Comment: Спасибо, тебе друг;)